# VB.NET 2 subreports based off of one dataset

Tags: vb.net, report

Problem description:
I have an iSeries query in VB.NET/VS 2008 that I need to run with 2 separate values of a same parameter and present in a report for A/B comparison. In other words - I want to see a report where the result of a run with parameter = value1 is on the left, same query with parameter = value2 on the right.

My initial idea was to use 2 tables on a report where each table would be based on result of each run from a DataSet (xsd), but I seem to be only able to specify the parameters on the ReportViewer level, which means I have 2 identical tables instead of A/B cases.

Obvious second way was to create 2 separate reports, each with its own parameter value and get them as subreports onto a main one. However, both subreports show up with "Error: Subreport cannot be shown". Is there a way to catch an error to see why?

I did a few other experiments, but I have a problem with the fact that it's not a "neat" solution.

What is the best way (a.k.a. best practices, industry standard, whatever you want to call it) to create this kind of A/B report? I was well sure that there is a well-known method to make this work, but to my surprise I haven't found anything except multiple copies of MSDN articles.

Answer (score 1):

To use two reports with the same dataset, you will need to add an event handler to your code to hook the SubreportProcessing event. When that event is fired you set the datasource to your dataset. The other thing that you need to look at is the report itself. If you are using Remotemode.Local for reportviewer you have the have a .rdlc extension of the report will never load. I keep the reports with both extensions. 1 that is run for my reporting server and the other for running local in my program.

I hope this helps!

Regards,
Willie